# Highlight alternating groups in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to highlight groups that have repeating values.  Lets say I have 2 columns ID and Name like below:

ID   Name
1    Bob
2    Bob
3    James
4    James
5    Steve
6    Sue
7    Sue
8    Sue

I want each group to have alternating colors, so Bob will be Red, James will be Blue, Steve Red, Sue Blue etc... alternating for each group.

I tried to use conditional format for Name, using "Format by" Field value and "Based on Field" Name, but is not working.

Thanks

Comment: To increase chances of receiving an answer, I suggest you to adopt the standard template: 1) Context, 2) Problem, 3) Example with a table, 4) Expected results in the table of (3) Example.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is not a pixel-perfect tool so this is not a built-in functionality. However, there might be some very complex and over engineered workaround which I do **not** suggest.

Instead, why don't you use what is available in Power BI?
For example, use a Matrix visualization either with +/- icons:
[image]

or without +/- icons:
[image]

Then, you can play with the stepped layout.

Comment: Thanks Seymour, that was my alternative solution as well,  I just started with Powerbi so wasn't sure if there was something simple that I was missing.